# How to detect all 10 disk drives on 2 Port Multipliers attached to Marvell 88SE9130 based HBA?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, hardware, sata

#### SilverStone EC05

I installed a [SilverStone EC05](http://www.silverstonetek.com/product.php?pid=335&area=en) SATA HBA/RAID controller on a Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit system, kernel 3.13.0-24-generic.

#### Marvell 88SE9130

This EC05 PCI Express card is based on a Marvell [88SE9130](http://www.marvell.com/storage/system-solutions/assets/Marvell-88SE9130-Product-Brief.pdf) chip.
`$ lspci` detects this controller as "`SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9128 PCIe SATA 6 Gb/s RAID controller with HyperDuo (rev 11)`”.

#### Sil3726 PM's

On both its **two** SATA ports, a Silicon Image [Sil3726](https://web.archive.org/web/20150320062221/http://siliconimage.com/solutions/pc/port-multiplier/) chip based PM (port multiplier) device is attached. Each port multiplier (PM) has 5 identical SATA drives attached. This makes 10 drives in total connected to the EC05. Each port multiplier is configured to be in port multiplier mode (not any kind of RAID mode). The motherboard BIOS seems to be configured to not load other BIOS-es because pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> during boot, doesn't result in entering into the Marvell BIOS.

#### Actual result

- When attaching PM#1 to EC05 SATA port#1, and PM#2 to EC05 SATA port #2, only the 5 drives on PM#1 are detected by the OS.
- When attaching PM#1 to EC05 SATA port#2, and PM#2 to EC05 SATA port #1, only the 5 drives on
  PM#1 are detected by the OS.
- When attaching PM#2 to EC05 SATA port#2, and
  disconnecting EC05 SATA port #1, only the 5 drives on PM#2 are
  detected by the OS.

#### Expected result

- When attaching PM#1 to EC05 SATA port#1, and PM#2 to EC05 SATA port #2, all 10 drives are detected by the OS.
- When attaching PM#1 to EC05 SATA port#2, and PM#2 to EC05 SATA port #1, all 10 drives are detected by the OS.

Related `$ dmesg` output section:

```
[    2.806779] ahci 0000:03:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    2.820401] ahci 0000:03:00.0: AHCI 0001.0200 32 slots 8 ports 6 Gbps 0xff impl SATA mode
[    2.820402] ahci 0000:03:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq pio
[    2.821223] scsi5 : ahci
[    2.821290] scsi6 : ahci
[    2.821346] scsi7 : ahci
[    2.821403] scsi8 : ahci
[    2.821458] scsi9 : ahci
[    2.821514] scsi10 : ahci
[    2.821569] scsi11 : ahci
[    2.821625] scsi12 : ahci
[    2.821673] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510100 irq 44
[    2.821675] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510180 irq 44
[    2.821676] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510200 irq 44
[    2.821678] ata9: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510280 irq 44
[    2.821679] ata10: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510300 irq 44
[    2.821681] ata11: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510380 irq 44
[    2.821682] ata12: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510400 irq 44
[    2.821684] ata13: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf0510000 port 0xf0510480 irq 44
[    3.124077] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    3.148049] ata6: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    3.148069] ata11: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.148091] ata12: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.148112] ata13: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 300)
[    3.148132] ata8: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    3.148148] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    3.148170] ata9: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    3.151632] ata13.00: ATAPI: MARVELL VIRTUALL, 1.09, max UDMA/66
[    3.181571] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    3.181572] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    3.181573] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    3.184009] ata10: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    3.211495] ata8.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDS5C3020BLE630, MZ4OAAB0, max UDMA/133
[    3.211496] ata8.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    3.211501] ata6.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDS5C3020BLE630, MZ4OAAB0, max UDMA/133
[    3.211502] ata6.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    3.211508] ata13.00: configured for UDMA/66
[    3.211510] ata9.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDS5C3020BLE630, MZ4OAAB0, max UDMA/133
[    3.211511] ata9.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    3.269922] ata10.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDS5C3020BLE630, MZ4OAAB0, max UDMA/133
[    3.269923] ata10.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    3.269927] ata5.00: ATA-7: OCZ-VERTEX, 1.3, max UDMA/133
[    3.269927] ata5.00: 125045424 sectors, multi 1: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    3.329205] ata8.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    3.329213] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    3.329217] ata6.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    3.358627] ata5.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[    3.358628] ata5.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[    3.358629] ata5.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[    3.387504] ata10.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    3.444077] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    3.444146] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      OCZ-VERTEX       1.3  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.444326] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] 125045424 512-byte logical blocks: (64.0 GB/59.6 GiB)
[    3.444352] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    3.444353] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.444361] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.444539] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    3.444653] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HDS5C302 MZ4O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.444732] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[    3.444733] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.444794] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    3.444796] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.444805] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.444855] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[    3.444919] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HDS5C302 MZ4O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.444990] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[    3.444990] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.445011] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[    3.445012] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.445021] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.445114] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    3.445173] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HDS5C302 MZ4O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.445233] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[    3.445287] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HDS5C302 MZ4O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.445348] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[    3.445407] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[    3.445408] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.445414] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[    3.445415] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    3.445854] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[    3.445856] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.445865] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[    3.445866] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    3.445888] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.445916] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    3.499601] scsi 12:0:0:0: Processor         Marvell  91xx Config      1.01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    3.499673] scsi 12:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg5 type 3
[    3.553712]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    3.553904] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.660336]  sdc: unknown partition table
[    3.660369]  sdb: unknown partition table
[    3.660442] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.660475]  sdd: unknown partition table
[    3.660510] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.660545] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[    3.712498]  sde: unknown partition table
[    3.712578] sd 9:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
[    4.102853] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    4.985641] ata11: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4000000 action 0xe frozen
[    4.985642] ata11: irq_stat 0x80000040, connection status changed
[    4.985643] ata11: SError: { DevExch }
[    4.985647] ata11: hard resetting link
[    5.705533] ata11: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    5.794270] ata11.00: ATA-8: Hitachi HDS5C3020BLE630, MZ4OAAB0, max UDMA/133
[    5.794271] ata11.00: 3907029168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    5.884054] ata11.00: configured for UDMA/133
[    5.913642] ata11: EH complete
[    5.942886] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Hitachi HDS5C302 MZ4O PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    5.972831] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[    5.972832] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] 4096-byte physical blocks
[    5.972854] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[    5.972855] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    5.972865] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    5.973000] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[    6.064214]  sdf: unknown partition table
[    6.064301] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
```

I can't find a utility to erase the Marvell 91XX BIOS in the hope that the RAID functionality is lost, and that the controller will act as a plain Host Bus Adapter (HBA) only.

How to detect all 10 drives, when connecting them via 2 port multipliers to both EC05 SATA ports?

Comment: Don't you have a second EC05? No... I thought the experiment with two boards would make picture brighter, bring more statistics and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Maximum Port Multiplier: 1

A maximum of 1 port multipliers can be connected to the Silverstone EC05 SATA RAID HBA according to MSU (Marvell Storage Utility) property page.

Silverstone technical support contacted the chip set manufacturer (Marvell) and:

> they think EC05 should able to support them (but the speed will limit
>   by the SATA port on EC05) They suggest you try them as following steps :
>
> 1. connect all HDDs and Sil3726 to EC05
> 2. install the control software from EC05’s CD
> 3. enter that software
> 4. set RAID mode to non-RAID and see you can see all HDDs on your system or not.

#### Marvell Storage Utility output

However there is no such option in MSU v4.1.0.1919 to "set RAID mode to non-RAID". The MSU lists these properties for "Adapter 0":

- BIOS Version: 1.0.0.1033
- Firmware Version: 2.2.0.1125
- Boot Loader Version: 1.0.1.0002
- Driver Version: 1.2.0.1002
- Chip Revision ID: B1
- Vendor ID: 1B4B
- Sub Vendor ID: 1B4B
- Device ID: 9130
- Sub Device ID: 9123

And at the bottom:

- Maximum PD per Adapter: 6 *(PD = Physical Devices)*
- Maximum VD per Adapter: 2 *(VD = Virtual Devices)*
- Maximum PD per VD: 2
- **Maximum Port Multiplier: 1**